# Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input['type=radio']:checked in jQuery 1.12.4 from 1.7.1js

Tags: jquery, jquery-1.7

The below code is not working where `$(this).children("div").children("input['type=radio']:checked` in jquery 1.12.4 JS and is working for 1.7.1

```
$(".highlightedRow").each(function () {
                if ($(this).children("div").children("input['type=radio']:checked").length == 0) {
                    $(this).css("background-color", "#F0AE3D");
                    flag = 1;
                }
                else {
                    $(this).css("background-color", "#99E599");
                }
            });
```

Please help if someone had similar problem while upgrading jquery

Comment: In all seriousness, you really shouldn't be using jQuery 1.x

Comment: That being said, the selector should probably be `input[type='radio']:checked` with quotes around the attribute value not `type=radio` otherwise it's looking for an attribute name 'type=radio'